# I want to get an LED to blink using the millis() function but my LED stays constantly on, what's wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, arduino, microcontroller, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I know there are other ways but I'd like to know what's wrong with my code and why it doesn't work. Pin 2 seems to constantly stay 'HIGH' despite the 'else if' statement.

```
const int led = 2;

int ledState = digitalRead(led);

const unsigned long interval = 1000;
unsigned long previousTime = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  unsigned long current = millis();

  if((current - previousTime >= interval) && (ledState == LOW))
  {
    digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
    previousTime = current;
  }
  else if((current - previousTime >= interval) && (ledState == HIGH))
  {
    digitalWrite(led,LOW);
    previousTime = current;
  }
}
```

Comment: You never update `ledState`.

Comment: You may want this: [https://forum.arduino.cc/t/how-to-invert-the-signal-from-a-digital-input-pin-in-software/175738](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/how-to-invert-the-signal-from-a-digital-input-pin-in-software/175738) and [https://forum.arduino.cc/t/reversing-digital-read-using-sml/280091](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/reversing-digital-read-using-sml/280091) and switch to just an if () with no else and no comparison to letState.

Comment: Thanks! So obvious, just a simple error and my brain was glitching out haha

Comment: there is a BlinkWithoutDelay example in the Arduino IDE Examples menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first comment said you did not update ledState. This is the problem. I believe a better solution to that is the following:

```cpp
const int led = 2;

const unsigned long interval = 1000;
unsigned long previousTime = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  unsigned long current = millis();

  if(current - previousTime >= interval)
  {
    digitalWrite(led,!digitalRead(led));
    previousTime = current;
  }
}
```

This reads the current led state and inverts it with `!digitalRead(led)` without the need of an if () else {}